# Fatal error: MPI_Gatherv

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, mpi

I'm new in MPI, trying to use MPI_Gatherv. There are two issues, first, the function doesnt collect all the items from all processors and sometimes it gives me fatal error. I dont understand what is going on!

Each Processor has a vector, that contains the indices of the minimum numbers, the size of the vector might be different in each processor.

Which part is wrong?
Any help would be appreciated.

My Code:

```
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &comm_size);
vector<int> localMin;
for (int i=0; i<numPerProc; i++)
{
    if (receive_buffer[i]==min) {
        int adjIndex=numPerProc*my_rank+i;
        localMin.push_back(adjIndex);
    }
}
// I thought I might be better use array instead of vector:
int nelements=localMin.size();
int* localMinArray=new int[nelements];
for (int i=0; i<nelements; i++) {
    localMinArray[i]=localMin[i];
}

int *counts = new int[comm_size];

// Each process tells the root how many elements it holds
MPI_Gather(&nelements, 1, MPI_INT, counts, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

// Displacements in the receive buffer for MPI_GATHERV
int *disps = new int[comm_size];
// Displacement for the first chunk of data - 0
for (int i = 0; i < comm_size; i++)
    disps[i] = (i > 0) ? (disps[i-1] + counts[i-1]) : 0;

int *allMin;
if (my_rank == 0)
    // disps[size-1]+counts[size-1] == total number of elements
    allMin = new int[disps[comm_size-1]+counts[comm_size-1]];


// Collect everything into the root
MPI_Gatherv(&localMinArray, nelements, MPI_INT, &allMin, counts, disps, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

The result is this:

```
Vector values in Rank  0: 4,11,
Vector values in Rank  1: 
Vector values in Rank  2: 24,31,
count values:
2,0,2,
disps values:
0,2,2,
allMin values:
4,11,0,-268435456,
```

These are the errors sometimes I get:

```
*** An error occurred in MPI_Gatherv
*** reported by process [3485859841,1]
*** on communicator MPI_COMM_WORLD
*** MPI_ERR_COUNT: invalid count argument
*** MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL (processes in this communicator will now abort,
***    and potentially your MPI job)
```

Comment: first you should pass `allMin` instead of `&allMin` to `MPI_Gatherv()`.

Comment: `MPI_ERR_COUNT` occurs if `counts` is `NULL, or if one of `counts[0:scomm_size-1]` is less than zero. try printing `nelements` and `counts` but only on master. note you do not need to allocate and populate `counts` nor `disps` on non root ranks.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Thank you for your response. Once I use "allMin" instead of "&allMin", I get all garbage numbers : 1094852496,32653,-1445708720,32740,

Comment: Actually I could fix it by making adding refrence to pointer in front of both allMin and localMinArray

Comment: i forgot to say you also need to use `localMinArray` instead of `&localMinArray`. is this how you fixed your code ? if not, can you please post the answer ?

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet I posted the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by doing the following change:

```
 MPI_Gatherv(*&localMinArray, nelements, MPI_INT,*&allMin, counts, disps, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

Comment: as i wrote in a late comment, the right fix is `MPI_Gatherv(localMinArray, nelements, MPI_INT,allMin, counts, disps, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);`